# Making class level DTO(instance variable) thread safe java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have Class level DTO. I have to make it thread safe.
why I want to do this is when Multiple request are coming to at same time data is swapping across threads.
I know Class level variables are not thread safe. But is there any way to make it thread safe.
I don't want to use synchronization  as its performance hit and wount work in load balance. Any Idea how to achieve this

Help appreciated :)

Thanks in Advance

Code:

```
public class MyExecutor implements Executor {

    private DataDTO DataDTO;
//Getters and setters
.
.
```

.
this DTO is sent to next layer
}

Comment: It is instance variable, not class.

Comment: Please read this [guide to writing a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: its instance variable(Wrapper class)

Answer (score 1):

Make the **DTO** immutable by declaring all class members as `final`, provide a constructor to set them (class members) when you create the DTO.

By doing that you make sure all values are read-only/set-once. Additionally, you can also delete (or not generate/provide) any setter. For instance:

```
public final class DataDTO {
  private final String data;
  private final String description;

  public DataDTO(String data, String description) {
    this.data = data;
    this.description = description;
  }

  public String getData() { return data; }

  public String getDescription() { return description; }
}
```

**NOTE:** If you need to extend from that class remove the `final`.